# Small count of packets leading to high RTT values

Tags: c++, networking

I have a pretty simple client/server application (TCP). 1 instance is sending 40 packets (smoothly distributed through 1 second) with around 1500 bytes data (part of data is timestamp). 2 instance is receiving these packets and sending back another packets with initial timestamp.
Now in 1 instance I'm measuring difference between current timestamp and timestamp from packets. So I'm getting somekind of handmade-RTT.
Also additionally I'm taking TCP RTT value for sockets with getsockopt and I see clearly:

- My RTT showing me values around 1 ms (which is expected at such low rate of packets)
- TCP RTT showing me ~40ms
  And I don't get it why. I know exactly that I'm receiving my packets early than 40 ms.

Also, If I will increase packets count from 40 to 600 for example, I will catch TCP RTT as ~150 mcs which is expected for my configuration.

Can anyone explain me this 40 ms from kernel side on low packets count?

Thank you

Comment: What sort of packets?

Comment: TCP connection and custom binary data

Comment: Please be less vague. _What sort of packets?_ Hand-constructed TCP packets? Individual TCP/IP packets with a flat payload? Or "packets" in some proprietary protocol that sits on top of TCP/IP? What? This is important because if you're not literally sending "a TCP/IP packet" but have some other notion of "packet" then TCP/IP may not be behaving the way you think it does. Don't forget, it wants to form full TCP/IP packets and it wants to use buffering to maximise overall throughput.

Comment: Hi, sorry. I will try to be more specific. I have protobuf over TCP/IP I'm sending packets in two steps: header and body (not TCP, but header and body of my protocol's meassge).

Comment: Okay, so there's no particular relationship to TCP/IP packets, and David is probably correct.

Answer (score 0):

40ms is the ACK delay on Linux. Here's what's happening:

1. Side A sends a packet with less data than the packet can hold.
2. Side B receives it and sets a 40ms ACK timer.
3. Side A's application calls `send`. But a packet is not sent because it is less data than the packet can hold and the last packet contains less data than the packet can hold. So the implementation waits to see if it can fit more data in the packet to avoid wasting network bandwidth.
4. The 40ms timer expires and side B sends an ACK.
5. Side A responds to the ACK by aborting its delay and sending the data it delayed now.

There are probably very good ways around this, but we'd need to know a lot more about your protocol and your actual requirements to make useful suggestions. Do not disable Nagle. That's almost always the worst "solution".

Comment: Thank you for answer. But in this case my handmade-RTT should be increased as well. But it's about 1 ms. Also this TCP RTT have a direct correlation with count of packets that I'm sending. So If I will send 80 packets I will have about 20 ms TCP RTT. So I can't clearly state that this is certainly delayed ACK.
Nagle algorithm is off. Buf when I'm turning it on I can see that TCP RTT dropping on half to 20 ms.

Comment: @AlanirAlonedaw How is this handmade RTT constructed? How do you know it's reliable?

Comment: @AlanirAlonedaw The 40ms delay isn't for all packets ever. It's for when there is an underflow. If you send enough data to fill a TCP/IP packet, you don't underflow. This is a feature!

Answer (score 0):

Delayed acknowledgment of packets is the answer. Less packets you will get.